# How to move cursor right or left every 5 second on FPS games?

Tags: java, minecraft, mousemove

Hello I was using "Auto mouse mover by Murgee.com" what this software basically doing he move the cursor on the screen right or left by pixels.
That's what I was trying to create I write this code simply to move my cursor in "Minecraft" and look left or right only every 5 second but unfortunately because this game lock my cursor in the Middle the code start glitching (The mouse moving completely fine in the background except the game).
If you have an idea what I should do tell even if it's not in java.

I try every single software that move the mouse to specific location it did the same as my script for some reason "Auto mouse mover By Murgee.com" is different.
This video maybe explain my problem

https://youtu.be/RezZQ_2yGxc

```
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Robot;
public class Location {
    public static final int FIVE_SECONDS = 5000;
    
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        
        while (true) {
            robot.mouseMove(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x+ 350, MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y); 
            Thread.sleep(FIVE_SECONDS);          
       }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please don't tag spam. This has nothing to do with Python or robots.

Comment: I didn't play the game you described. You need to determine if the problem is that Robot doesn't have the ability to move the cursor in the game or if the game locks the cursor. You can test your program in a game interface that allows you to move the cursor, such as the setup interface.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Python for macros & automatisation for any scenarios and mostly in Minecraft as it's quite easy to use.
To run your script you would need to install Python and IDLE Python v3.9 (the software that will run the scripts). Then you can use this code I made and adjust the values for your needs and press F5 (in IDLE) to launch.

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import win32api, win32con

print('Running')
while (keyboard.read_key() == 'p') == False:
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, 100, 0, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(5)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, -100, 0, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(5)
print('Stopped')
```

Hopefully it will help you, if you need more, you can find some documentation & tutorials online.